# C array and pointer to array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a simple question..
I have a C program..
I have a array of long and I would like to to pass a pointer to this array into two function.
Is correct to pass the array in this way?

```
long[] myArray


void myFunction1(long *myArray[]){

*myArray[0] = 1;

}

void myFunction2(long *myArray[]){

*myArray[1] = 2;

}
```

Is correct this?

Comment: Nope, this is not correct. Change your function parameter to `long myArray[]`, and assign value without the asterisk.

Comment: log *array[] can be multidimensional array, an array is a pointer.
*myarray[1] = 2 is like you dereference an element and access a subelement *myarray[1] = myarray[0][1]

Comment: Why don't you test it out and see if it works

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Since Arrays are already pointers their content is already passed as a reference (as opposed to as value). So any modifications inside the function will persist after the function call ends.

Comment: @Hoffmann: No, arrays are not pointers. Arrays are arrays. Array expressions *decay* to pointers in most, but not all contexts.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). It explains the often confusing relationship between C arrays and pointers better than anything else I've read.

Comment: Wow that is a very interesting read, thank you. But my comment still stands, the changes performed on the array will persist after the function call ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this is not correct because when you declare a variable like this -

```
long *myArray[]
```

it represents an array which can hold **long pointers**, not long values. I am guessing (from your function body) this is not what you intend to do.

Change your function parameter to `long myArray[]`, and assign value without the asterisk.

Like this -

```
void myFunction1(long myArray[]){
    myArray[0] = 1;
}

void myFunction2(long myArray[]) {
    myArray[1] = 2;
}
```

Or, if you like to use pointer, then -

```
void myFunction1(long *myArray){
    myArray[0] = 1;
}

void myFunction2(long *myArray) {
    myArray[1] = 2;
}
```

In both of the cases, remember to ensure that the size of your array is at least 2.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's think about it:

```
long myArray[3]; // This is an array of 3 long's

long *myArray[3]; // Is this? No, this is an array of 3 pointers to longs.
```

That pretty much tells you the answer.

```
void myFunction1(long *myArray[]){
```

This is not how you pass an array to a function (long or otherwise). You need to take just an array:

```
void myFunction1(long myArray[]){
    myArray[0] = 1;
```

or you can take a pointer:

```
void myFunction1(long *myArray){
    myArray[0] = 1;
```

That works because arrays decay to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `void myFunction1(long *myArray[])`, I suspect you are making two mistakes.

One is that I think you intended this to be a pointer to the array. However, the brackets, `[]`, bind more tightly to the identifier, `myArray`, than the asterisk, `*`, does. So the parameter is `long *(myArray[])`, which is an array of pointers to `long`, but I think you intended a pointer to an array of `long`, which would be `long (*myArray)[]`.

You actually could declare the function with this parameter, pass it a pointer to the array, as with `myFunction1(&myArray)`, and use the pointer inside the function, as with `(*myArray)[0] = 1;`.

However, C gives us a shortcut, and not using that is the second mistake. If you declare the parameter as `long myArray[]`, then it looks like an array but it is actually converted to `long *myArray`, which is a pointer to `long`. Then you can pass the array as `myFunction1(myArray)`. Although `myArray` is an array, C converts it to a pointer to the first element. So the argument `myArray` will match the parameter `long myArray[]`. Then, inside the function, you can use the pointer with `myArray[0] = 1;`.

The shortcut results in shorter notation and is generally considered to be more natural notation, so it is preferred.